# Is the Shuriken(5) actually 5 weapons or a single weapon?

Tags: dnd-4e, ranged-attack

Is the "Shuriken(5)" entry in Players Handbook actually 5 weapons, i.e. the player can attack 5 times without pulling out more shurikens, or a single "notional" weapon and all 5 of the shurikens are thrown in a single attack ?

Answer (score 16):

### It's five single weapons.

Because five shurikens cost one gold, you buy them in units of 5. But they are used singly.

Comment: I believe this is also the number to which a single enchantment can be applied, much like how other ammunition is enchanted in batches of twenty.

Comment: @DanRasmussen - PHB220 - *Some monsters, such as werewolves, are susceptible
to attacks made by silvered weapons. A single
weapon, 30 arrows, 10 crossbow bolts, 20 sling bullets,
or 5 shuriken can be silvered at a cost of 500 gp.
This cost represents not only the price of the silver,
but the time and expertise needed to add silver to a
weapon without making it less effective.*

Comment: Interesting ... my argument is the Shuriken(5) is in the weapons, like dagger, but the arrows, etc. are in ammunition. Also the silvering only indicates the "unit size", not they are individual items. My gut feeling because of the way WotC wanted to keep things simple, is it is a single "item"

Comment: @DanRasmussen considering they are thrown weapons rather than ammo, and that this could have potentially interesting effects if you have implement prof light blades (you now have 5 same enchantment implements). I doubt this is the case

Comment: @waxeagle Actually this discussion on enchanting make me more convinced that the Shuriken(5) is a single weapon, otherwise you can enchant one Shuriken(5), and give one each to five parties members, so for the cost of a single enchantment, everyone has a magic weapon. And extend this to many different effects, so each player can have one of every thrown variant.

Comment: @SteveC Where is stated that enhancing a bunch of 5 shurikens costs as enhancing a single throwing axe? The silver coating cost is not the same as making them magical (and thus, returning).

Comment: @ErikBurigo I'm way more concerned about the potential brokenness of dual implement spellcasting if shurikens can be enchanted for 1/5 the cost.

Comment: @waxeagle If you consider them as 5 single weapons, how are you able to enchant them at 1/5 of the normal cost?

Comment: @ErikBurigo I don't think you can. the implication that you can is all kinds of broken.

Comment: @waxeagle In fact... I didn't understand why you told me that you are concerned about the "1/5 enchantment cost" if I am absolutely contrary to that interpretation. :D

Answer (score 1):

You should treat them like you would throwing daggers or even arrows, they are basically like ammunition without a weapon to fire them (unless you count your hands). The only reason you buy them in fives, is because it comes to a round number of money, I believe they are usually 1gp. Similarly, you don't buy arrows individually. You use one per attack (unless the attack states differently) so you could count them each as individual weapons that get used up when they are fired, much like arrows. If you are DM you could possibly make them use a minor action to take out the shurikens initially, like you would a sword or a bow. But thats up to the DM. basically you wouldn't generally fire all 5 in one attack.